# Hudson intermittently doesn't trigger jobs

Tags: windows, hudson

I have a hudson 1.370 setup running on Windows 2003 R2 under a VMware VM, with ~30 jobs, some of them triggered on a cron job, and some triggered on a URL change.

Most of the time, everything works fine. But twice now, I'll leave for the evening, come back in the morning, and nothing will have triggered.  No failed jobs, no notices in the log files, nothing.  I tried kicking off a job manually before changing anything else, and it ran fine.  All of the URL change triggers that weren't activated the night before are activated when I restart hudson, since the URLs changed sometime between 8p-12p.

It seems like hudson just randomly stops polling for triggers.  I've checked all of the log files in the hudson directories, and the system event log, and there's nothing in there. I'm willing to upgrade hudson to see if it helps, but the changelog doesn't point to any bug fixes that would affect this.

I realize that's not much info for you to go on, but I don't even know how to debug this.  Is there more logging I could turn on?  If I setup some external method to notify me while this is happening, what could I do to find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem, and filed a hudson bug report: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-8304